# Popup on popup, the popup below disappears

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am using the following listeners on the showwindowpopup to grey out(opaque) the background so that nothing is seen. But when I try to close this window, a confirmation window has to appear to confirm from user, but when this confirmation window appears the showwindowpopup behind it which is behind it gets greyed out as well and is not seen.

```
show: function(win) {
           if (this.modal) {
                     var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');
                     for(var i=0; i<dom.length;i++){
                         Ext.get(dom[i]).setStyle('opacity',1);
                     }
           }
},


 close:  function(win) {
                 if (this.modal) {
                     var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');
                     for(var i=0; i<dom.length;i++){
                         Ext.get(dom[i]).setStyle('opacity',0);
                     }
                 }
}
```

Can someone tell me how can I resolve this? I want the background to be greyed out except the showwindowpopup and the confirmation window. I want the showwindowpopup to be seen whene the confirmation window is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Constrain the "show window popup" to the parent panel?